# SQL query to return n top records which have a null field or records grouped by that field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table A which has a filter column

```
| id |  name  | filter |
| 1  |  joe   |  a     |
| 2  |  anna  |  a     |
| 3  |  mike  | null   |
| 4  |  frank | null   |
| 5  |  sarah |  b     |
| 6  |  jamie |  b     |
```

Assume the records are ordered by id. Records with the same value for filter should be count as one only.

TOP(1) should return

```
| id |  name  | filter |
| 1  |  joe   |  a     |
| 2  |  anna  |  a     |
```

TOP(2) should return

```
| id |  name  | filter |
| 1  |  joe   |  a     |
| 2  |  anna  |  a     |
| 3  |  mike  | null   |
```

TOP(3) should return

```
| id |  name  | filter |
| 1  |  joe   |  a     |
| 2  |  anna  |  a     |
| 3  |  mike  | null   |
| 4  |  frank | null   |
```

TOP(4) should return

```
| id |  name  | filter |
| 1  |  joe   |  a     |
| 2  |  anna  |  a     |
| 3  |  mike  | null   |
| 4  |  frank | null   |
| 5  |  sarah |  b     |
| 6  |  jamie |  b     |
```

Comment: Edit the question with your desired result.

Comment: This question is very unclear. It might be better to explain what requirement you're trying to meet (i.e. why you want the results you do) in addition to what results you want. It doesn't make sense to always return more rows than the `TOP(n)` that you're asking for, and the sort order you want to apply isn't clear either.

Comment: assume the records are sorted by id. I want to be able to ask for the `TOP(n)` records but count the records with the same filter value as one only

Comment: If you add another row ID 7 with filter `a`, you want it displayed on `TOP(1)`?

Comment: yes, because when ordered by id, there is a filter `a` record in the first position, so I'm expected to return all the records with the filter `a`...

Comment: although it's quite unlikely it will happen. records with similar filter should be inserted one after another...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a windowed `MIN()` to group values with the same filter (and NULL values on different groups), then use a `DENSE_RANK()` to flatten the values so it can be filtered later.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Values') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Values

CREATE TABLE #Values (
    ID INT IDENTITY,
    Name VARCHAR(10),
    Filter VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #Values (
    Name,
    Filter)
VALUES
    ('joe', 'a'),
    ('anna', 'a'),
    ('mike', NULL),
    ('frank', NULL),
    ('sarah', 'b'),
    ('jamie', 'b'),
    ('john', 'a')

DECLARE @v_TopFilter INT = 4 -- Your top filter here

;WITH MinimumByFilter AS
(
    SELECT
        V.*,
        MinimumIDByFilter = MIN(V.ID) OVER (
            PARTITION BY 
                V.Filter,
                CASE WHEN V.Filter IS NULL THEN V.ID END)
    FROM
        #Values AS V
),
DenseRank AS
(
    SELECT
        M.*,
        DenseRank = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY M.MinimumIDByFilter ASC)
    FROM
        MinimumByFilter AS M
)
SELECT
    D.ID,
    D.Name,
    D.Filter
FROM
    DenseRank AS D
WHERE
    D.DenseRank <= @v_TopFilter
ORDER BY
    D.ID ASC
```

You can check what the functions return here:

```
ID  Name    Filter  MinimumIDByFilter   DenseRank
1   joe     a       1                   1
2   anna    a       1                   1
7   john    a       1                   1
3   mike    NULL    3                   2
4   frank   NULL    4                   3
5   sarah   b       5                   4
6   jamie   b       5                   4
```

Answer (score 2):

On second thought, you are trying to select first *n* distinct filters. Just find the smallest id per filter and number them:

```
DECLARE @A TABLE(id INT, name VARCHAR(100), filter VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @A VALUES
(1, 'joe',     'y' ), -- 1st
(2, 'anna',    'x' ), -- 2nd
(3, 'mike',    NULL), -- 3rd
(4, 'frank',   NULL), -- 4th
(5, 'sarah',   'x' ),
(6, 'jamie',   'y' ),
(9, 'forrest', 'z' ); -- 5th

WITH filter_minid AS (
    SELECT filter, MIN(id) AS minid
    FROM @A
    GROUP BY filter, CASE WHEN filter IS NULL THEN id END
), filter_minid_number AS (
    SELECT filter, minid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY minid) AS rn
    FROM filter_minid
)
SELECT *
FROM @A a 
INNER JOIN filter_minid_number ON a.filter = filter_minid_number.filter OR a.id = filter_minid_number.minid
WHERE rn <= 5 -- this is where you filter for n distinct ids
```

Result:

```
| id | name    | filter | filter | minid | rn |
|----|---------|--------|--------|-------|----|
| 1  | joe     | y      | y      | 1     | 1  |
| 2  | anna    | x      | x      | 2     | 2  |
| 3  | mike    | NULL   | NULL   | 3     | 3  |
| 4  | frank   | NULL   | NULL   | 4     | 4  |
| 5  | sarah   | x      | x      | 2     | 2  |
| 6  | jamie   | y      | y      | 1     | 1  |
| 9  | forrest | z      | z      | 9     | 5  |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE ( id INT,  name  varchar(10), filter varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES
(1 ,'joe', 'a'),
(2 ,'anna', 'a'),
(3 ,'mike', null),
(4 ,'frank', null),
(5 ,'sarah', 'b'),
(6 ,'jamie', 'b')

DECLARE @TOP INT = 3

SELECT id, name, filter FROM 
    ( SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SUB_RNK) RNK
        FROM ( SELECT *, 
            MIN(id) OVER(PARTITION BY ISNULL(filter,id) ) SUB_RNK
          FROM @Tbl ) T1
    ) T2
WHERE 
    T2.RNK <= @TOP
```

Result: (for top 3)

```
id          name       filter
----------- ---------- ----------
1           joe        a
2           anna       a
3           mike       NULL
4           frank      NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

using subquery

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `top` (IN x INT UNSIGNED)
BEGIN
select * from tableA where `filter` in (select distinct `filter` from tableA LIMIT x )
END
```

using join

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `top` (IN x INT UNSIGNED)
    BEGIN
    select * from tableA A 
      join (select distinct `filter` from tableA LIMIT x ) AA
      on A.`filter` = AA.`filter`
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by filter,
                                         (case when filter is null then id end)
                                end) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum < ?  -- whatever your limit is;
```

If you wanted to use `top` for this, you can use `top with ties`:

```
select top (?) with ties t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by filter,
                                         (case when filter is null then id end)
                                end) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by seqnum;
```